# Decrypt notification data and use data in iOS - flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification

I am implementing notification in flutter app and checking for iOS. Scenario is when user receive notification in iOS I want to encrypt that data to use for further feature implementation. Here is my function which I write in `AppDelegate` file

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    

    self.flutterMethodChannelLocalNotification.invokeMethod("localnotification", arguments: userInfo["data"] ?? "")// output: "some-value"
    let data = userInfo["data"] as? [String:Any]
    let param : [String:Any] = [KeyCenter.kUserId: data?[KeyCenter.kNotificationForUserId] ?? "" ,
                                KeyCenter.kGroupId: data?[KeyCenter.kGroupId] ?? "",
                                KeyCenter.kChatType: data?[KeyCenter.kChatType] ?? ""]
    print("Param data = \(param)")
    viewModel = ViewModel()
    viewModel.doubleTickCallApi(params: param, completion:{ (sucsses, message) in
        if sucsses{

        }else{
            print(message ?? "Unexpected")
        }
        completionHandler(.newData)
    })
    // Inform the system after the background operation is completed.
}
```

when I print `param` it will be `Param data = ["userId": "", "chatType": "", "groupId": ""]`. How to handle optional `userInfo["data"]` value here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is I have to parse notification data in json and then use it

```
let data = userInfo[AnyHashable("data")] as? String
let jsonData = data?.data(using: .utf8)!
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

 let param : [String:Any] = [KeyCenter.kUserId: json[KeyCenter.kNotificationForUserId] ?? "" ,
                                    KeyCenter.kGroupId: json[KeyCenter.kGroupId] ?? "",
                                    KeyCenter.kChatType: json[KeyCenter.kChatType] ?? ""]
```